# Why am I getting a Link error when I try to overload an operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, lnk2005

I'm doing a project exercise, where I'm revising a previous project of a class I created called `Polynomial` to use a link list (the original used arrays). The link list uses a template so that any type can be passed into it.

One of the problems I ran into with this project exercise is that I am trying to pass an object of type `PolyNumber` (from a class I made), and the link list bag I made has a function that compares any item (using `==`) that is passed to it.

It works fine with regular types, such as `int` and `string`, but runs into problems with custom made object types. So I figured out how to overload the `==` operator in the `PolyNumber` class. By itself, it works when I test this class, but when I use this type with the `Polynomial` class with the Link List implementation, I get errors such as the following for each method in the Polynomial class:

```
Error   LNK2005 "public: __thiscall PolyNumber::PolyNumber(int,int)" (??0PolyNumber@@QAE@HH@Z) already defined in Polynomial.obj    Project11
```

Here's my code for those files, but as you can see in the code, there are other files that go with this code, such as the `LinkedBag` for the link list object, but for space I just include these:

*PolyNumber.h*

```
#pragma once

class PolyNumber
{
public:
    PolyNumber();
    PolyNumber(int set_coefficent, int set_degree);
    void setDegree(int set);
    void setCoefficient(int set);
    int getDegree();
    int getCoefficient();
    friend bool operator== (const PolyNumber& p1, const PolyNumber& p2);
    friend bool operator!= (const PolyNumber& p1, const PolyNumber& p2);

private:
    int degree;
    int coefficient;
};
```

*PolyNumber.cpp*

```
#include "PolyNumber.h"


PolyNumber::PolyNumber()
{
    coefficient = 0;
    degree = 0;
}
PolyNumber::PolyNumber(int set_coefficent, int set_degree)
{
    coefficient = set_coefficent;
    degree = set_degree;
}

void PolyNumber::setDegree(int set)
{
    degree = set;
}
void PolyNumber::setCoefficient(int set)
{
    coefficient = set;
}
inline int PolyNumber::getDegree()
{
    return degree;
}
inline int PolyNumber::getCoefficient()
{
    return coefficient;
}

bool  operator== (const PolyNumber& p1, const PolyNumber& p2)
{
    return (p1.coefficient == p2.coefficient && p1.degree == p2.degree);
}

bool operator!= (const PolyNumber& p1, const PolyNumber& p2)
{
    return !(p1 == p2);
}
```

*Polynomial.h*

```
#pragma once
#include "PolynomialInterface.h"
#include "LinkedBag.cpp"
#include "PolyNumber.cpp"
static const int POLYNOMIAL_SIZE = 10;

class Polynomial : public Polynomoal_Interface
{
public:
    //Cunstructs am empty Polynomial  
    Polynomial();

    //Copy constructor
    Polynomial(Polynomial& copy);

    /** Cunstructs a Polynomial with a client defined Polynomial
    @param an array of non-negative integer coeffient that does not exceed POLYNOMIAL_SIZE, each coeffient in the array has a power that correspounds
    to the respective value of the location of the ceffient in that array. */
    Polynomial(int coeffient[POLYNOMIAL_SIZE], int size);

    int degree();
    int coefficient(int power);
    bool changeCoefficient(int newCoefficient, int power);
private:
    //static const int POLYNOMIAL_SIZE = 10;
    //int polynomial[POLYNOMIAL_SIZE];
    LinkedBag<PolyNumber> bag;
};
```

*Polynomial.cpp*

```
#include "Polynomial.h"


Polynomial::Polynomial()
{

}
Polynomial::Polynomial(Polynomial& copy)
{
    std::vector<PolyNumber> copyFrom = copy.bag.toVector();
    for (int i = 0; i < copyFrom.size(); i++)
    {
        bag.add(copyFrom[i]);
    }
}
Polynomial::Polynomial(int coeffient[POLYNOMIAL_SIZE], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        PolyNumber number = { coeffient[i], i + 1 };
        bag.add(number);
    }
}
int Polynomial::degree()
{
    int max = 0;
    std::vector<PolyNumber> result = bag.toVector();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        if (result[i].getDegree() > max)
        {
            max = result[i].getDegree();
        }
    }
    return max;
}
int Polynomial::coefficient(int power)
{
    int result = 0;
    std::vector<PolyNumber> powerOf = bag.toVector();
    for (int i = 0; i < powerOf.size(); i++)
    {
        if (powerOf[i].getDegree() == power)
        {
            result = powerOf[i].getCoefficient();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
bool Polynomial::changeCoefficient(int newCoefficient, int power)
{
    PolyNumber number = { newCoefficient, power };
    int result = coefficient(power) + newCoefficient;
    bag.remove(number);
    number.setCoefficient(result);
    bag.add(number);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could really do with a minimal example; and the command you're using to build

Comment: Why do you include the `.cpp`-files? That's basically _never_ what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have `#include "PolyNumber.cpp"` instead of `#include "PolyNumber.h"`.

That makes all the methods defined in `PolyNumber.cpp` to be included (and re-defined) in `Polynomial.cpp`.
The same will happen with `LinkedBag`.

Why are you including `cpp`s?

Comment: I actually switched it around to test to see if it would work, and just left it like that when I made this post, I originally had "PolyNumber.h" , but either way I get that error